# nodejs application insigths string property suddenly limited to 1024

Tags: azure-application-insights

I used for > 1.5 years to use trackEvent in AI nodejs package with a property with various payload text.

until now, I was able to send large payload (sent many time >53k length string)

[image]

suddenly, starting on 18th of october 2018, all string longer than 1024 chars are truncated.

I looked into github repo and or new release and I can't understand if expected or not ...

AI "version": "1.0.6"

I suspect that version 1.0.6 has this new limitation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is new in 1.0.6 and appears to be a bug.

**Context:**

The Application Insights SDK for Node had always intended to truncate custom dimensions to 1024 chars, but this logic was broken in some cases. As part of the changes in 1.0.6 to support nested objects in custom dimensions, the truncation logic was fixed.

We perform this truncation because your telemetry has a chance of being dropped entirely by the Application Insights backend if custom dimensions are longer than the limit specified in the schema. **However**, the [limit in the schema is 8192 rather than 1024](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/blob/master/EndpointSpecs/Schemas/Bond/EventData.bond#L19).

I've opened a bug to track fixing this: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/444

Comment: thanks for the clarification, this was exactly what I was looking for and trying to understand the future limit of backend. I do suspect that there would be the exact same limitation for other API (dotnet/etc). ?

Comment: The 8192 limit should be enforced by the backend, and I would expect other SDKs (such as for .NET) to truncate to that to avoid the backend enforcement

Comment: checked and confirmed, my brain was mixing up the former long message telemetry from nodejs. (we have different clients technology pushing similar telemetry)